# How do I refactor out one function from a javascript module to another .js file, but which acts on the base object?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a JS module containing two pieces of functionality as below.

**I want to extract one piece of functionality so it is in another file but acts on the base object.**

I want to refactor the following so that addIconLayer() moves to another .js file, as that function isn't really about the core base functionality, but is an optional component. I can't work out the syntax for this, mainly as I'm not very familiar with this javascript module pattern (though I am familiar with classes/methods/etc in other languages.).

```
<script src="basemodule.js"></script>
<script>basemodule.init('somevalue');</script>
```

where basemodule.js contains, effectively:

```
var basemodule= (function ($) {

    var map;
    var icons;

    return {

        init(parameter1){
            map = new L.map(...); // Loads leaflet.js
            icons = getIconSet();
            addIconLayer(parameter1);
        },

        getIconSet(){
            icons = ...; // Assigns the icons
        },

        /* THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WANT TO MOVE TO A NEW CLASS - it still needs to act on map icons */
        addIconLayer(parameter1){
            map.doStuffToMap();
            var foo = icons;
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I want something like this, and have tried (to no avail):

```
<script src="basemodule.js"></script>
<script>basemodule = basemodule.init();</script>
<script src="iconlayer.js"></script>
<script>iconlayer.init(basemodule, 'somevalue');</script>
```

iconlayer.js:

```
// Class which enables an icon layer to be added
var iconlayer = (function ($) {

    var map;

    return {

        init: function(mapinstance, parameter1) {
            map = mapinstance.map;

            map.doStuffToMap();
            var foo = icons;
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

but this and similar stuff doesn't work.

I can't find any good examples of similar extension/refactoring. Can anyone point me to the right way to do this?

Comment: IF you want/wish for more precise control of module loading I would suggest requireJS  http://www.requirejs.org/

Comment: What specific errors are you receiving when you run this?